# How to convert a text file to CSV using Bash

Tags: bash, csv

I've a text file with thousand of lines in it (each line has an email address) and I'd like to convert those to a CSV file using bash. The problem is I'm not well versed with Bash, so not sure how to go about doing it.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: File example:**

```
email@meail.com
email2@meail.com
email3@meail.com
email4@meail.com
```

Comment: sample input and desired output

Comment: a file where every line is just an email address is already a CSV. is there additional information in each line?

Comment: @SeanBright are you sure? I've tried to use the file to import into Drupal and got an error

Comment: would you care to share that error with the rest of us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly but it should work:

```
while read email; do echo '"'${email//\"/\"\"}'"'; done < inputfile.txt > output.csv
```

This escapes `"` with `""` which is how CSVs are escaped in Excel land.